# url not found in zend framework though working for index page

Tags: zend-framework

i am trying to develop website using zend framework so i had created one index.php file where all my requests goes and c.reated two controller one is IndexController and other is TestController

```
Class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "Index Index Jamla";
    }
    public function displayAction(){
        echo "Index Display Jamla";
    }
}
```

now when i access the url http://test/
it correctly calls IndexController and its IndexAction function
but when i access the url http://test/index/index
it displays the message url /index/index was not found on this server same it does when i access http://test/test/index

though http://test/ is equivalent to http://test/index/index

Comment: I removed `netbeans` tag as it has nothing in common with the question

Answer (score 5):

The rewrite rules for Zend Framework are not working.

`http://test` works because Apache is defaulting to run index.php which will run your application.  The router will see no URL parameters so it routes to index controller index action.  When you attempt to access anything else, Apache is handling the request and is not rewriting it to index.php so you are getting a 404 not found.

Make sure the .htaccess containing the rewrite rules is in your public folder.  Also check that Apache allows processing of .htaccess files for your document root by setting `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf and/or httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: Also make sure that mod rewrite is enabled in apache.conf. I forget that on almost every new installation!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set AllowOverride to All in your Apache configuration and have enabled the mod_rewrite extension

Answer (score 0):

Silly but can you recheck again either index.phtml file exists under views/scripts/index/