# 404 error after website migration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I developed a website using CodeIgniter on a server, and I'm trying to migrate it to the production server but I'm getting a 404 error. Again, the website is working perfectly on the development server so all I did was copy the files and the database from one server to the other.

Here is the .htaccess file of the website folder (copied from the original installation):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

On the original server, the main URL was http://myowndomain.com/websitename/preview

Now it should be like http://www.websitename.com/preview

So yes, the website is in a subfolder in both cases, and the fies are exactly the same. I also checked the Apache configuration using "phpinfo()", and I can see that the "mod_rewrite" module is loaded.

The home page is working though ( http://www.websitename.com/preview ), it's able to run the index.php file, but all the links on the page don't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check if `RewriteBase /preview/` is working for you along the rest of the same sattings. That is in case _www.websitename.com_ is root of vhost and _preview_ is subdirectory.

Comment: @Tpojka I'm getting the same results. I forgot to mention that I can access the main page since it only has to run the index.php file. However all the other links don't work.

Comment: why don't you uncomment the line `#RewriteBase /` by removing the `#`

Comment: @cmorrissey I did, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: This is probably because `AllowOverride` is set to `None` for that `Directory` in httpd.conf.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838471/url-not-found-in-zend-framework-though-working-for-index-page/8844729#8844729

Comment: @drew010 Yes! It worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1319182 No prob - glad that did the trick.  Feel free to upvote that answer if it helped :)

Comment: Have you followed the file and class naming way as said on here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @drew010 Feel free to write an actual answer and I'll accept it.